# Real time form validation to validate more then 1 rule

Tags: jquery

How can i validate a text box but with 2(or more) validation ruls?

(this one is not good, suppose i enter "f$444" it says ok.

```
 $(function () {
    var RegEx = "/^[0-9]+$/";
    var $message = $('#message');
    $('#text').on('input', function () {          
      if ($('#text').val().length < 5) {
            $message.text("minimum 4 digit");
        } else {
            $message.text("OK!");
      }
      if ($('#text').val().contains("$")) {
          $message.text("must not contains $");
      }
    });
});
```

And how can I achieve that with nicer writing, like:

```
clientValidator({
    $('#text').val().length < 5: "minimum 5 digit",
    contains("$"):               "must not contains $",       
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *else if*

```
$(function () {
    var RegEx = "/^[0-9]+$/";
    var $message = $('#message');
    $('#text').on('input', function () {          
      if ($('#text').val().length < 5) {
            $message.text("minimum 4 digits");
      } else if ($('#text').val().length > 20) {
            $message.text("maximum 20 digits");
      } else if ($('#text').val().contains("$")) {
            $message.text("must not contain $");
      } else {
            $message.text("OK!");
      } 
    });
});
```

Comment: is $('#text').val().contains("$")- correct syntax?
contains("$") exist? this line is not working.